# How do I translate "large-scale optimization problem" to Spanish language?

Tags: optimization, translation-request, mathematical-spanish

I'm writting my PhD thesis in Spanish, and I need to know how to write "large-scale optimization problem" to Spanish language.

If additionally you could give a refence for that translation, I would be very glad.

Comment: being spanish I agree with the answer of @KeyFlex

Comment: @Masacroso, I'm spanish too. Did you hear that therminology before? Maybe in some congress, paper, lesson...

Comment: no. Pero no creo haya necesidad de eso... Las terminologías en matemáticas son muy variables, incluso en inglés. La "oficialidad" no existe como tal en matemáticas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google Translator for that. Just type English to Spanish in Google and you will find many. In Spanish "large-scale optimization problem" means "**Problema de optimización a gran escala**"

Comment: I need an "official" translation. I could also provide the translation you suggest, but I have to use the terminology that the spanish optimization researchers use.

Comment: If you google the suggested translation you will see it is often used.

Comment: @kimchilover, you are right!